# Mac OS software for periodical work break

Tags: macos, software-rec, time-management

Does anybody know any Mac OS X software which allows control of computer work time and reminds about break after period of time?

Something like [gnome-typing-monitor](http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2009/12/gnome-typing-break.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dejal Time Out](http://www.dejal.com/timeout/) supports both "microbreaks" and regular breaks.

[image]

---

AntiRSI is another option.

> AntiRSI is a program for Mac OS X that helps prevent RSI (repetitive strain injury) and other computer related stress. It does so by forcing you to take regular breaks, yet without getting in the way. It also detects natural breaks so it won't force too many breaks on you.

[image]

---

[MacBreakZ](http://www.publicspace.net/MacBreakZ/) is commercial software that can tell you what to do in your breaks.
[image]