# Health Monitoring Alert for OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS software for periodical work break](https://superuser.com/questions/245705/mac-os-software-for-periodical-work-break)

I have an application on Windows which checks for continuous uses. It alerts me to take rest after 15-20 minutes when I am continuously working on the machine.

Is there any application on OS X which does same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Time Out](http://www.dejal.com/timeout/) is one.  [Tiny Alarm](http://plumamazing.com/mac/tinyalarm/) is a more general timer (easy to restart) that runs in the menu bar.  [Here are some references](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=os-x%20take%20a%20break&btnG=Google%20Search) to a bunch more break timers.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this myself, but a colleague of mine mentioned this to me a while back, as he had RSI troubles. He found it useful.

http://www.publicspace.net/MacBreakZ/